# Running and checking the result of a sql agent job through a shell script

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlcmd, sql-job

Basically I need to create a shell script to:

- run a SQL agent job on a remote server
- wait for it to run
- check for the completion status and be able to save it / output it so it can be used further

The way I'm planning it is to create a stored proc with a job name parameter like this:

```
-- Start job
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = @job_name

-- Wait for Job to finish
DECLARE @job_status INT
SELECT @job_status = current_execution_status FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=<server>;','exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_job @job_name = @job_name ')

WHILE @job_status <> 4
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03'
    SELECT @job_status = current_execution_status FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=<server>;','exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_job @job_name = @job_name')
END

-- Get Result

SELECT TOP 1 @job_history_id = activity.job_history_id
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs jobs
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity activity ON activity.job_id = jobs.job_id
    WHERE jobs.name = @job_name
    ORDER BY activity.start_execution_date DESC

SELECT history.run_status
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory history
WHERE history.instance_id = @job_history_id
```

Ideally, I could run every SQL agent job through this stored_proc so I can very easily call this stored_proc via  `sqlcmd` with the job name as a parameter and save the output as the result of the job.
As I'm not the most experienced with SQL Server, I come to you all for help.

1. Is my stored proc efficient/functional? can anyone enlighten me to a better way of doing this?
2. Should this stored proc be created on the msdb database and if so should it be saved as a system object  ?
3. Is this going to post a problem with migrations or any management (i.e. special actions to migrate SQL versions / to different servers in order to keep this stored proc)?

Thanks in advance for any support.

Comment: Running a loop to check when something is finished is not the best idea but can be used. What are you trying to achieve here i.e. what happens after the job is finished?

Comment: this job will restore some dbs, after that runs successfully tests will be triggered

Comment: Why not add tests as an extra Job Step?

Comment: separation really, tests are ran using custom-built frameworks and as such, they are to be managed by CI Server and not by the SQL server. the major idea here would be to be able to wait for the restore job and check if it was successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Anyone looking for the answer to this, I came to a stored procedure that works quite well:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_sp_start_job_wait
(
@job_name SYSNAME,
@WaitTime DATETIME = '00:00:10', --check frequency
@JobCompletionStatus INT = null OUTPUT
)
AS

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @job_owner sysname

-- Create temp table with xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs structure
CREATE TABLE #xp_results (job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
last_run_date INT NOT NULL,
last_run_time INT NOT NULL,
next_run_date INT NOT NULL,
next_run_time INT NOT NULL,
next_run_schedule_id INT NOT NULL,
requested_to_run INT NOT NULL, -- BOOL
request_source INT NOT NULL,
request_source_id sysname COLLATE database_default NULL,
running INT NOT NULL, -- BOOL
current_step INT NOT NULL,
current_retry_attempt INT NOT NULL,
job_state INT NOT NULL)


SELECT @job_id = job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
WHERE name = @job_name

SELECT @job_owner = SUSER_SNAME()

INSERT INTO #xp_results
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, @job_owner, @job_id


-- Start the job if the job is not running
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #xp_results WHERE running = 1)
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = @job_name

-- wait a couple of seconds to compute
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'

DELETE FROM #xp_results
INSERT INTO #xp_results
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, @job_owner, @job_id

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #xp_results WHERE running = 1)
BEGIN

WAITFOR DELAY @WaitTime

DELETE FROM #xp_results

INSERT INTO #xp_results
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, @job_owner, @job_id

END

SELECT top 1 @JobCompletionStatus = run_status
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
WHERE job_id = @job_id
and step_id = 0
order by run_date desc, run_time desc

IF @JobCompletionStatus = 1
PRINT 'The job ran Successful'
ELSE IF @JobCompletionStatus = 3
PRINT 'The job is Cancelled'
ELSE
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('[ERROR]:%s job is either failed or not in good state. Please check',16, 1, @job_name) WITH LOG
END

RETURN @JobCompletionStatus

GO
```

Comment: I execute job using BAT script: `osql -S "10.210.69.69" -U "sa" -P "xxxx" -Q "exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'testRestoreAndReplace' "`